# I need script to resize the div height as proportional to width

Tags: html, css, grid-layout

I am working with grid layout design. But i dont how to resize the div height as proportional to width. I need to resize the div height in responsive. Let me know pls if have any script..

Comment: Typically the % is used for responsive designs.
`width: 80%;` and `height: 80%` will scale the component as the window size changes.

Comment: I know, Not for single div. I am having multiple div`s in the home page and i need to show in grid view as responsive. So let me know if any script. I need to resize all the divs in the grid view as according to the div width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, just add `resize` event listener and set height to elements:

```
var RATIO = 0.7;

$(window).on("resize", function() {
    $("#mydiv").height($("#mydiv").width() * RATIO);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/teu7vere/

Comment: Ok i`ll check with this script.